# Possible display options in Drupal views

Tags: views

I am a newbie into Drupal 7.
I am learning D7 views. I exported a view and found :

```
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
```

with no permission array to specify the user group who can access this view.

Which user group does it take by default?
Also, in my custom view in code I have replaced it with following:

```
$handler->display->display_options ['access']['type'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['role'] = array(
    3 => '3',
);
```

It is working fine. I want to know all possible values of $handler->display->display_options this array. Where can I find all these options? Is there any documentation available for this?

Answer (score 0):

Restrictions to access view can be set through Views UI to "role", "permission" or "none". See [this page in Views documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1490434).

As for "role", those are IDs of different roles on your website. You can find those IDs in adiministration *admin/people/permissions/roles* - just hower over role edit link, number is in its URL.

Comment: It just gives options for $handler->display->display_options['access']['type'], I want to have a look at all of them. Is there any doc available for this?